# Should the copy.com tag be removed?

Tags: discussion, support, status-declined, tags

It currently has no watchers. At this time, there are 13 questions tagged with [copy.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/copy.com).

[copy.com](https://copy.com/) has been discontinued.

I saw it in this recent question: [compare and move a file from one directory to another in unix,](https://askubuntu.com/q/1088477/248158)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I went through all the questions tagged with [copy.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/copy.com).  Each and every one of those 12 questions (the 12 remaining after you removed the tag from the post you referenced) is actually in relation to the now-defunct `copy.com` agent and client.

Because those questions are all using the tag correctly, and it's a significant number of posts (12 is not a small number of legitimate-tag-use questions...) **I'm not comfortable removing the tag** because the legacy questions that still use it are all legitimate questions.

To that end, I suggest you just remove the tag from the offending post you outlined.

I have made revisions to the tag wiki for that tag to indicate this tag should not be used, and is kept for legacy purposes in the interim.

Comment: I'm personally going to vote to close those 12 questions as off topic because "This describes a problem that can't be reproduced, that seemingly went away on its own or was only relevant to a very specific period of time. It's off-topic as it's unlikely to help future readers". I'm not going to say I'm certain this should be done (so I'll leave it up to reviewers to decide).

Comment: @Tim that might be something you propose in a different meta post then.  Especially since the service is no longer available, we can't actually give any answers to unanswered ones.

Comment: I've voted and I'll see if they get closed. If they don't, I'll post the meta question and suggest that they are.